# Exiting HTML5 Fullscreen Video Breaks Poster Images on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video, android-fullscreen

I have a scenario where I have search results that contain video content.  Each video item in the results has a thumbnail sized video player, so up to 10 html 5 video players can exist per result set. When the user clicks the thumbnail, the video goes fullscreen and automatically plays the video.  When the user exits fullscreen, the video pauses.

This all works great on iOS devices, but on android I have significantly more even handling to worry about.  Here's the logic as I have it now:

```
    goFullScreen: function (ev) {
      var el                = ev.target,
          isVideoFullscreen = el.webkitDisplayingFullscreen;

      el.webkitEnterFullScreen();
      // the approach below is the only way I could get reliable fullscreen detection on android
      $(window).bind("resize", function (e) {
        if (isVideoFullscreen != el.webkitDisplayingFullscreen) {
          isVideoFullscreen = el.webkitDisplayingFullscreen;

          if (isVideoFullscreen) {
            el.load();
            el.play();
          } else {
            el.pause();
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Even though iOS does not need all of this even handling, it still works fine.  The problem with android is that when I exit fullscreen, the video pauses, but the poster image is replaced for the video I just paused with a still from the video (to be expected), but all  subsequent videos in the result set have their poster image replaced with an ugly video icon.  As a result, the thumbnails just look like broken videos.  But if you tap them they still go fullscreen and play just fine.

I'm testing on a Galaxy Nexus and a Galaxy SII.  I can say that the el.pause() is not responsible, if removed the video will continue playing in the thumbnail and all video tags below it will still have the broken poster icon.

This works as expected on desktop webkit browser and on iOS devices.  Only experiencing this issue on android 4+ devices.  Also remember that the EnterFullscreen request has to happen in the scope it's in.  Calling out of this scope will prevent it from working due to security restrictions on mobile devices.  I've pretty much exhausted all ideas so I'm looking here to hopefully get a few more.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, is el.webkitEnterFullScreen(); working for you? If yes? then what version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on trying to solve all of the bugs and quirks in Android.  Instead, I'm just linking directly to the mpeg4 videos from the thumbnails.  So no more video tags, no more event handling.

The only side effect is that some versions of android display a dialog on how you want to play the video, which is not ideal but better than any alternative I could find. Fortunately the iOS experience is consistent no matter what approach I take.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, could you plz tell how you have overcome it using above solution? any info would be helpful